# Converting integer format date to double format of date

Tags: r, date, posix

I have date format in following format in a data frame:

```
Jan-85
Apr-99
1-Nov
Feb-96
```

When I see the `typeof(df$col)` I get the answer as "integer".

Actually when I see the format in excel it is in `m/d/yyyy` format.  I was trying to convert this to date format in R.  All my efforts yielded NA.

I tried `parse_date_time` function.  I tried `as.date` along with `as.character`.  I tried `as.POSIXct` but everything is giving me NA.

My trials were as follows and everything was a failure:

```
as.Date.numeric(df$col,"m%d%Y")

transform(df$col, as.Date(as.character(df$col), "%m%d%Y"))

as.Date(df$col,"m%d%Y")

as.POSIXct.numeric(as.character(loan_new$issue_d), format="%Y%m%d")

as.POSIXct.date(as.character(df$col), format="%Y%m%d")

mdy(df$col)

parse_date_time(df$col,c("mdy"))
```

How can I convert this to date format?  I have used lubridate package for parse_date_time and mdy package.

dput output is below

```
Label <- factor(c("Apr-08", 
"Apr-09", "Apr-10", "Apr-11", "Aug-07", "Aug-08", "Aug-09", "Aug-10", 
"Aug-11", "Dec-07", "Dec-08", "Dec-09", "Dec-10", "Dec-11", "Feb-08", 
"Feb-09", "Feb-10", "Feb-11", "Jan-08", "Jan-09", "Jan-10", "Jan-11", 
"Jul-07", "Jul-08", "Jul-09", "Jul-10", "Jul-11", "Jun-07", "Jun-08", 
"Jun-09", "Jun-10", "Jun-11", "Mar-08", "Mar-09", "Mar-10", "Mar-11", 
"May-08", "May-09", "May-10", "May-11", "Nov-07", "Nov-08", "Nov-09", 
"Nov-10", "Nov-11", "Oct-07", "Oct-08", "Oct-09", "Oct-10", "Oct-11", 
"Sep-07", "Sep-08", "Sep-09", "Sep-10", "Sep-11"))
```

Comment: A month and a year is not a date.

Answer (score 1):

`NA` is typically what you get when you misspecify the format. Which is what you do. That said, if your data is really looking like the first example you gave, it's impossible to simply convert this to a date. You have two different formats, one being month-year and the other day-month.

If your updated date (i.e. `Dec-11`) is the correct format, then you use the `format` argument of `as.Date` like this:

```
date <- "Dec-11"
as.Date(date, format = "%b-%d")
# [1] "2017-12-11"
```

Or on your example data:

```
as.Date(Label, format = "%b-%d")
# [1] "2017-04-08" "2017-04-09" "2017-04-10" "2017-04-11" "2017-08-07" "2017-08-08"
# [7] "2017-08-09" "2017-08-10" "2017-08-11" "2017-12-07" "2017-12-08" "2017-12-09"
```

If you want to convert something like `Jan-85`, you have to decide which day of the month that date should have. Say we just take the first of each month, then you can do:

```
x <- "Jan-85"
xd <- paste0("1-",x)
as.Date(xd, "%d-%b-%y")
# [1] "1985-01-01"
```

More information on the format codes can be found on `?strptime`

Note that R will automatically add this year as the year. It has to, otherwise it can't specify the date. In case you do not have a day of the month (eg like Jan-85), conversion to a date is impossible because the underlying POSIX algorithms don't have all necessary information.

Also keep in mind that this only works when your locale is set to english. Otherwise you have a big chance your OS won't recognize the month abbreviations correctly. To do so, do eg:

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_TIME", locale = "English_United Kingdom")
```

You can later set it back to the original one if you must, or restart your R session to reset the locale settings.

**note**: Please check carefully which locale notations are valid for your OS. The above example works on Windows, but is not guaranteed on either Linux or Mac.

**Why you see integer**

The fact that these string values are of integer type, is due to the fact that R automatically convert character vectors to factors when reading in a data frame. So `typeof()` returns `integer` because that's the internal representation of a factor.

Comment: I got `as.Date("Dec-11", format = "%b-%d") # NA` and `Sys.setlocale("UK") # Error in Sys.setlocale("UK") : argument 'category' incorrect`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper sorry, oversight of me. You have to specify that this is the value for the argument `locale`. I updated the answer, thank you for notifying me.

Comment: `Sys.setlocale(locale = "UK")` works but `as.Date("Dec-11", format = "%b-%d") ` still doesn't :(

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper which OS are you on? these things are actually done by the OS, not by R itself. So that might be a difference as well. Can you give me also the output of `Sys.getlocale()` to see where the problem might be?

Comment: my OS is Windows 7 64-bit and `Sys.setlocale(locale = "UK") #[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252"`

Comment: I had to do this `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")` for your code to work

Comment: Thanks this worked.  I was getting confused with the date format showing excel rather than format being displayed on R console

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper That's very weird. I have the exact same OS, and the output of `Sys.setlocale` clearly shows that also LC_TIME is set to English. Keep in mind you first have to set your locale, and then run the code for conversion.

Comment: @JorisMeys I made my own question about it, it'll be easier that way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44723690/unexpected-behavior-of-sys-setlocale

Comment: as.Date(loan_new$earliest_cr_line,c("%b-%d","%b-%y"))

Comment: as per the answer i used above syntax.  Only %b-%d is getting converted and month and year is not getting converted and returning NA values for those dates which has Month and Year liked as show in my opening text                                                                                  Jan-85  (Not getting converted shown as NA)
Apr-99  (Not getting converted shown as NA)
1-Nov    (got converted)
Feb-96  (Not getting converted shown as NA)      Pls Help

Comment: @VikramRS That's why I wrote that Jan-85 can NOT be transformed to a date because you don't know the day. And the format has to be a single character string as explained in the help file. So you can't convert different formats at the same time. See my update and don't just copy the code. I write that explanation for a reason.