# Unexpected behavior of Sys.setlocale

Tags: r, locale

Please see the code below, I have to change my locale to be able to convert a date. My first attempt is unsuccessful, my second attempt works, though it seems redundant and doesn't change the output of `Sys.getlocale`.

My OS is Windows 7 64-bit

```
Sys.getlocale() # "LC_COLLATE=French_Belgium.1252;LC_CTYPE=French_Belgium.1252;LC_MONETARY=French_Belgium.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=French_Belgium.1252"
date <- "Dec-11"
as.Date(date, format = "%b-%d")     # NA
Sys.setlocale(locale = "UK")        # "LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252"
locale2 <- Sys.getlocale()
as.Date(date, format = "%b-%d")     # NA
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English_United Kingdom")
locale3 <- Sys.getlocale()          # "LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252"
as.Date(date, format = "%b-%d")     # "2017-12-11"
locale2 == locale3                  # TRUE
```

I can skip the first call to `Sys.getlocale` and the date conversion will work:

```
Sys.getlocale() # "LC_COLLATE=French_Belgium.1252;LC_CTYPE=French_Belgium.1252;LC_MONETARY=French_Belgium.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=French_Belgium.1252"
date <- "Dec-11"
as.Date(date, format = "%b-%d")     # NA
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English_United Kingdom") # 
locale4 <- Sys.getlocale()          # "LC_COLLATE=French_Belgium.1252;LC_CTYPE=French_Belgium.1252;LC_MONETARY=French_Belgium.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252"
as.Date(date, format = "%b-%d")     # "2017-12-11"
```

But this doesn't work :

```
Sys.getlocale() # "LC_COLLATE=French_Belgium.1252;LC_CTYPE=French_Belgium.1252;LC_MONETARY=French_Belgium.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=French_Belgium.1252"
date <- "Dec-11"
as.Date(date, format = "%b-%d")     # NA
Sys.setlocale(locale = "English_United Kingdom") #
locale5 <- Sys.getlocale()          # "LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252"
as.Date(date, format = "%b-%d")     # NA
```

This is related to this question : [Converting integer format date to double format of date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44721152/converting-integer-format-date-to-double-format-of-date/44721568?noredirect=1#comment76428112_44721568)

Comment: Add your OS information to it too, that's key in all questions regarding locales and date formats. Also, what happens if you do `Sys.setlocale(locale = "English_United Kingdom")` instead of `Sys.setlocale(locale = "UK")?

Comment: please see updated answer

Comment: I've done some more testing too, and unless I'm missing something, this looks like a bug. Only thing to figure out is where the bug actually sits. It might be R, but this might be Windows too. I'll check further tonight on another system, and keep you updated. I posted in R-devel as well, in the hope some of the R gurus can shine their light on this : http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/LC-TIME-not-set-correctly-by-Sys-setlocale-td4740135.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [answer of prof. dr. Brian Ripley](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/LC-TIME-not-set-correctly-by-Sys-setlocale-td4740135.html) :

This is expected behaviour in Windows. On other systems, the underlying function for formatting `strptime()` uses the OS specific strptime function, but Windows doesn't have one. So R uses a substitute function in the case of non-english day or month names. As you have your standard locale on French, your R is set up to recognize french day and month names/abbreviations.

This substitue function for strptime uses its own mapping of those day and month names, but this mapping is refreshed ONLY when `"LC_TIME"` is set specifically. At least this is the case for R 3.4.0 and earlier versions using the same mechanism.

So contrary to my first impression, this is not a bug but a feature :-)

Comment: A feature that makes Sys.getlocale return inaccurate information for LC_TIME though

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Actually not. The "feature" is `strptime()` not detecting the change in LC_TIME correctly.